# Regular expressions with datagridview

Tags: c#, regex, datagridview

I want to make in my program a button that imports data from hostile.
And displays this data in my datagridview. Im using regular expressions to extract ip, website name, comment etc.

```
 localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 jw smartsite.jw
127.0.0.1 dev.filepresso.com dev.filepresso.com.pl dev.filepresso.pl dev.filefly.pl

    #89.31.66.248 sp.biatelbit.pl

    192.168.72.51 subversion.biatel.com.pl

    127.0.0.1 bip.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 bip.augustow.wrotapodlasia.pl
    127.0.0.1 rpowp.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 cms.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 cms-test.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 wp.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    #127.0.0.1 zamowienia1.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    127.0.0.1 tv.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    #127.0.0.1 radny.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    127.0.0.1 lomza.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    #127.0.0.1 rot.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    127.0.0.1 wrotapodlasia1.pl

    #127.0.0.1 strategia.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    #127.0.0.1 si.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    127.0.0.1 bip.um.suwalki.wrotapodlasia1.pl
    127.0.0.1 efort1.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 bialystok.smartsite.bit-sa.pl
    127.0.0.1 bipnowy.bialystok.pl
    127.0.0.1 nowy.bialystok.pl
```

This is part of this hostile.
This is `Regex` that im using:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex (@"^(#*\s*)(\d[1-3]\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)\s*(\s*|\.)(([a-z]*(\.|\s|\-))*)/gm");
```

And this is path to my hosts file:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\praktykant1\Desktop\hosts.txt";
```

It's my first time when im using regular expressions so i have no idea how to do it.

I have to take ip from hostfile and insert it into ip table in my `datagridview`
This is code of my load button, that load into my datagridview already existing xml file.

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                hostsDataSet.Clear();
                hostsDataSet.ReadXml(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
```

So to sum up i want to know how to use regular expressions to load my hostfile into my datagridview.

Comment: Do not use `/gm` in the regex, you should just use `RegexOptions.Multiline` if you need multiline mode on, and use `Matches` to get all matches. And I guess you want to match 1, 2 or 3 digits with `\d[1-3]`? Then replace with `\d{1,3}`.

Comment: RegEx can be a fine art, best bet is to experiment in a browser based sandbox such as http://www.regexe.com/ to get the result you want then copy that expression into your code.

Comment: I used regex101.com. I want match 1 or 2 or 3 in first digit in the ip, becouse if it's begin with other digit, then ip is wrong.

Comment: Please check my regex: [`^[# ]*(?<ip>[1-3]\d{2}(?:\.\d){3})[ .]*(?<name>[a-z]*(?:[. -]*[a-z]*)*)`](http://goo.gl/Rl5Cgu). Is it what you need? See *Table* tab.

Comment: On regex101.com it matches only 1 line, almost at the end. I used gm on this site, but i don't have problem witch matching pattern to hostfile. I have no idea how to use it in my program.